# parsing user_agent_string in postgres sql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm stuck trying to parse a `user_agent_string` in postgres sql.

This is an example string:

> Stucko/4.13.0 (iPhone; iOS 9.2.1; Scale/2.00)

I want to extract just the `iOS 9.2.1` part. I'm inclined to think this can be down with regular expressions but I'm not very familiar with that and thus haven't been able to figure out a usable solution.

Comment: Could you give more examples ? That would facilitate find a pattern.

Comment: Is `iOS` the only OS you're looking to extract? That makes things pretty easy I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `split_part()` to do this:

```
split_part(user_agent_string, ';',2)
```

This will split the `user_agent_string` by the delimiter `;` and return the second element, which is your OS, in this example.